# How to get current View in Service

Tags: android

I would like to send phone screen to desktop. (using socket) like a Mobizen App

First, I need to take phone screen.

I knew how to save the Activity screen.
like this.

```
 View v1 =L1.getRootView();
             v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             Bitmap bm = v1.getDrawingCache();

             FileOutputStream out = null;
             try {
                 out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/capture.png");
                 bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out); // bmp is your Bitmap instance
                 // PNG is a lossless format, the compression factor (100) is ignored
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
```

but This is only possible Activity.

I would like to capture a screen in the background as a service.
And current screen of phone will send to desktop.

So, How to get current View in Service?

Thanks regards.

Comment: This is not possible unless your device is rooted

Comment: You should not even do that. If you want to make some actions of UI thread after something happens in the Service - then you should use [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) or some other method of inter-process communication

Answer (score 2):

Your service is running in a separate context than your Activity. To make the screenshot you need to be in the context of the Activity. Even if you could define your Activity context public static and access it from your service, you run the risk, that the context disappears while you are working on it in your service. If your activity is killed and your service is still running, the context is gone, so this is not the right approach.

So the recommended way is to actually make the screenshot in your Activity. If the event to make the screenshot is coming from your Service, you can send a BroadcastMessage from the Service to your activity to trigger the screenshot there.

Comment: what if activity kills that is not a right approach to keep static reference of some activity

Comment: I wrote exactly this - the context disappears when your activity is killed, so no reason to downvote my answer

Comment: Edit the answer and mention the risk and I will upvote this.